# How to use Character.toUpperCase?

Tags: java, string, uppercase

```
    for(int i=0;i<chInp.length();i++)
    {
        if(chInp.charAt(i)=='a' || chInp.charAt(i)=='e' || chInp.charAt(i)=='i' || chInp.charAt(i)=='o'|| chInp.charAt(i)=='u')
        {
            Character.toUpperCase(chInp.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

This program searches through a String, identifies any vowels and puts them in uppercase. I tested and it is able to successfully identify the vowels, however it is not putting them in uppercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this line puts `chInp.charAt(i)` in `uppercase` you don't assign the value:

```
Character.toUpperCase(chInp.charAt(i));
```

**UPDATE**: As you are not allowed to do this:

```
chInp.charAt(i) = Character.toUpperCase(chInp.charAt(i));
```

To assign new value use a `StringBuilder`

Before the loop create it:

```
StringBuilder mString = new StringBuilder(chInp);
```

Inside the loop, to assign the new value:

```
mString.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(chInp.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: you can't assign a value to `charAt(i)`!

Answer (score 2):

`Character.toUpperCase()` is a method which, when given a `char` as an argument, will return another `char` which is the uppercase version of that `char`, for some definition of "uppercase". What it will NOT do is "magically" change the underlying storage where that char comes from so that the extracted value is replaced with the new value. Two reasons for that:

- Java is pass by value;
- changing that in the original source would be considered a side effect.

Even if the two statements above were not true for Java, you would have another problem anyway, and that problem is simple: `String` is immutable; you cannot change the contents of a `String`.

Use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
final int len = chInp.length();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);

char c;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = chInp.charAt(i);
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            sb.put(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            break;
        default:
            sb.put(c);
    }
}

return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new string and append the characters to it:

```
String s="";
for(int i=0;i<chInp.length();i++)
 {
    if(chInp.charAt(i)=='a' || chInp.charAt(i)=='e' || chInp.charAt(i)=='i' || chInp.charAt(i)=='o'|| chInp.charAt(i)=='u')
    {
        s+=Character.toUpperCase(chInp.charAt(i));
    } else s+=chlnp.charAt (i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not adding the new upper case letter to the String, so you are not seeing the results. Modifying one character in a String is not possible in Java, so you have to take a slightly different approach. I would turn the String in to a character array, modify the values I needed to, then turn it back in to a String.

```
    char[] letters = chInp.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
        if(letters[i]=='a' || letters[i]=='e' || letters[i]=='i' || letters[i]=='o'|| letters[i]=='u'){
            letters[i] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[i]);
        }
    }

    chInp = new String(letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer has been selected and all answers given are GOOD answers, I'm highly surprised that no one thought of **String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)**.  There is no need to manually check if your string has vowels in it, as **String.replaceAll** will do it for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    String testStringNoVowels = "fly fly fly fly fly";
    char[] vowels = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    System.out.println("Test String (With Vowels) Before: " + testString);
    System.out.println("Test String (No Vowels) Before  : " + testStringNoVowels);
    for (char vowel : vowels) {
        testString = testString.replaceAll(String.valueOf(vowel), String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(vowel)));
        testStringNoVowels = testStringNoVowels.replaceAll(String.valueOf(vowel), String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(vowel)));
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Test String (With Vowels) After : " + testString);
    System.out.println("Test String (No Vowels) After   : " + testStringNoVowels);
}
```

Results:

[image]